# How to import styles without file extension in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, sass

I'm using Next.js, TS, and SCSS.
In every `app/*/page.tsx` or `components/*/page.tsx`, there is a line for stylesheet like `import style from "styles/*/index.module.scss"`.
I think these lines are too long.
Therefore I would like to shorten them to `import style from "styles/*"`, like import ts module with `import module from "*"` instead of `import module from "*/index.ts"`.
Is there any way to do this?

I tried

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  ...
  "paths": {
    "@styles/*": ["./styles/*/index.moudle.scss"], // add this line
    ...
  }
  ...
}

// app/**/page.tsx

import style from "@styles/login";
...
```

, but `Next.js` said `Module not found: Can't resolve '@styles/login'`.

Also TS said `Cannot find module "@styles/login" ts(2307)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, you can use path aliases in your TypeScript configuration (tsconfig.json) to create shorter import paths for your stylesheets. Here's how you can set it up:

1. Open your tsconfig.json file.
2. Locate the "paths" property and add an entry for your stylesheets. For example:{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
   "@styles/*": ["styles/*"]
   }
   }
   }
3. Save the changes to your tsconfig.json file.
4. Now you can use the shortened import path in your code.
   For example:
   import style from "@styles/login";

This will import the index.module.scss file from the styles/login directory.

Make sure that the path specified in your "paths" configuration matches the actual file path to your stylesheets. Also, ensure that the stylesheets are placed in the correct location relative to your project's root directory.

Once you have set up the path alias, Next.js should be able to resolve the module correctly, and TypeScript should no longer show the "Cannot find module" error.

Note: After making changes to your tsconfig.json file, you may need to restart your development server for the changes to take effect.